# How to auto renew Azure AD App client secrets and store in Key Vault

Tags: azure-active-directory, active-directory, devops, azure-keyvault

Now that Microsoft has removed the "never expire" option from Azure AD app client secrets (and because generally it's good practice) I'm looking for a way to auto-renew a client or generate a new one and then save that value to Azure Key Vault.

I know of various ways to save a value to the Key Vault but I can't see any nice ways to programmatically track the expire of client secrets and renew/create new ones.

Does anyone know how to start going about this?

Answer (score 0):

I can call [this graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to add a new secret.

The result is succeed.

`But I can't see the newly created secret` in Azure portal -> Azure AD -> target application -> Certificates & secrets, I can only see it in the Manifest blade. It's weird.

[image]

I also found an [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/395895/can-i-generate-azure-ad-client-credentials-secrets.html) about using powershell command to create secrets. `New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId "YourAppObjectId"`

Comment: I'll have a play with this, looks promising.